# update IP and Port with user input in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, devops

I have .env file that needs to updated dynamically with a shell script from the user input.
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.55:30091/db_name
I have a shell script

```
#/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter the Database IP:" DATABASE_IP
read -p "Please enter the Database Port:" PORT
echo $DATABASE_IP $PORT
sed -i "s/${DATABASE_IP}" ~/.env
```

I am not familiar with the string manipulation.
How can I complete the shell script to update a .env file

Comment: The `sed` command `s///` substitutes one value by another one. I don't see a replacement value in your command.

Comment: Have a look at `envsubst`? Perhaps it is exactly what you need, and easier to use. The idea would be that you create a template environment file, `.env_template`, where you use a variable for the IP address _jdbc:postgresql://$DATABASE_IP:30091/db_name_, and then use _envsubst_ to create from this the actual .env file.